# Запуск скрипта в других скриптах Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скрипт 1:

```
public class randomizer : MonoBehaviour {

public void fear()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
    if (rand<55){
        Debug.Log("нападают");
    }
    if (rand >= 55) {
        Debug.Log("убегают");       
    }

}

}
```

Скрипт 2:

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 Player;
    private Vector2 PlayerDirection;
    private float Xdif;
    private float Ydif;
    private float speed;
    private float distance;
    private bool stun;
    private float stuntime;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        stuntime = 0;
        stun = false;
        speed = 6;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
        distance = Vector2.Distance (Player, transform.position);
        Player = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform.position;
        if (stuntime > 0) {
            stuntime -=Time.deltaTime;
                } else {
            stun = false;
                }
        if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
                        Xdif = Player.x - transform.position.x;
                        Ydif = Player.y - transform.position.y;
                        PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
                }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Playerhit){
                if (Playerhit.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
                        stun = true;
                        stuntime = 1;
                }
    }
}
```

Скрипт 3:

```
public class EnemyRun : MonoBehaviour {

        public AnimationClip a_idle;
        public AnimationClip a_walk;
        public AnimationClip a_run;
        public AnimationClip a_jump;

        //public Transform target;
        public Vector3 target;
        public int moveSpeed;
        public float rotationSpeed;
        float corutTimer;
        float dist;
        float rRot;

        Ray ray, rayUp, rayDown, rayDownLeft, rayDownRight, rayRight, rayLeft, rayRun;
        RaycastHit hit, hitDown, hitRight, hitLeft;

        Vector3 p, p1;

        bool startCast;
        bool turnedAccess;
        int tempTurn;

        Animation anim;
        private Transform myTrans;

        void Awake()
        {       
                turnedAccess = true;
                myTrans = transform;
                moveSpeed = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(6,8.5f));
                rotationSpeed = moveSpeed * 0.5f;
                corutTimer = 0.3f/moveSpeed;
                startCast = true;
                anim = this.GetComponent<Animation>();
        }

        void Start () {
                GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
                //target = go.transform;
                StartCoroutine(OrientationEnemy());
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
                        RunFromPlayer ();
        }

        void RunFromPlayer()
        {       if (target != Vector3.zero)
                {
                        if (dist > 2)
                        {       
                                if (Physics.Raycast(rayDown, out hitDown, 2)){
                                        if (turnedAccess)
                                        {
                                                Quaternion rawRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTrans.rotation,
                                                                                             Quaternion.LookRotation(target - myTrans.position),
                                                                                         rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
                                                myTrans.rotation = new Quaternion(0, rawRotation.y, 0, rawRotation.w);
                                        }

                                        myTrans.position += myTrans.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                                }else 
                                {
                                        myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -45, 0));
                                }


                        }
                        else 
                        {
                                anim.Play (a_idle.name);
                        }
                }else anim.Play (a_idle.name);
        }

        IEnumerator OrientationEnemy()
        {       while (startCast){
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(corutTimer);
                        //проверяем дистанцию до цели
                        if (target !=null)
                        {
                                dist = Vector3.Distance(myTrans.position, target);
                        }
                        //проверяем наличие поверхности под телом
                        rayDown = new Ray (transform.position, transform.forward + Vector3.down);
                        rayDownLeft = new Ray (transform.position, -transform.right + Vector3.down);
                        rayDownRight = new Ray (transform.position, transform.right + Vector3.down);
                        //если дистанция до цели больше и есть поверхность делаем проверки для определения непроходимых мест
                        if (dist > 2 && Physics.Raycast(rayDown, out hitDown, 2))
                        {       //луч вперед из центра
                                ray =  new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
                                //луч около головы
                                rayUp = new Ray (transform.position + Vector3.up*0.5f, transform.forward);

                                //проверяем левую и правую сторону
                                rayRight = new Ray (transform.position + Vector3.down * 0.5f, transform.right + Vector3.up*0.5f);
                                rayLeft = new Ray (transform.position + Vector3.down * 0.5f, -transform.right + Vector3.up*0.5f);

                                if (Physics.Raycast(rayRight, out hitRight, 2) && hitRight.collider.name !="Enemy" || Physics.Raycast(rayLeft, out hitLeft, 2) && hitLeft.collider.name !="Enemy")
                                {
                                        turnedAccess = false;
                                }
                                else 
                                {       
                                        if (Physics.Raycast(rayDownLeft, out hitDown, 2) && Physics.Raycast(rayDownRight, out hitDown, 2))
                                                turnedAccess = true;
                                }

                                if ((Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2) && hit.collider.name == "Collider") || (Physics.Raycast(rayUp, out hit, 2) && hit.collider.name !="Enemy"))
                                {               
                                        tempTurn = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0,1.9f));
                                        if (tempTurn == 0) myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -45, 0));
                                        else myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 45, 0));

                                        /*if (hitRight.collider != null && hitLeft.collider == null)
                                        {
                                                myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 45, 0));
                                        }
                                        else if (hitLeft.collider != null && hitRight.collider == null)
                                        {
                                                myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -45, 0));
                                        }
                                        else {
                                                tempTurn = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0,1.9f));
                                                if (tempTurn == 0) myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -45, 0));
                                                else myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 45, 0));
                                        }*/

                                }
                                //отрисовка линий для теста
                                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + Vector3.up*0.5f, transform.forward);
                                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward);
                                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward*2 + Vector3.down*2);
                                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + Vector3.down * 0.5f, transform.right + Vector3.up*0.5f);
                                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + Vector3.down * 0.5f, -transform.right + Vector3.up*0.5f);

                                if (target != Vector3.zero)
                                anim.Play(a_run.name);
                        }
                }
        }

        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
                if (other.name == "Player") {
                        rRot = Random.Range (0, 270); //рандомный кгол поворота для убегания
                        myTrans.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, rRot, 0));
                        rayRun = new Ray (myTrans.position, transform.forward*30);
                        target = rayRun.GetPoint(30); //точка в качестве таргета
                }
        }

}
```

В 1 скрипте `if (rand<55)` должен выполняться скрипт 2, а `if (rand>=55)` должен выполняться скрипт 3. Применяться это должно ко всем объектам с тегом "enemy". Как такое можно реализовать?

Попытка 1:

```
public class randomizer : MonoBehaviour {
public enemy enemyRun;
private float Xdif;
private float Ydif;
private Vector3 Player;

public void fear()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
    if (rand<55){
        enemyRun.Update();
        Debug.Log("нападают");
    }
    if (rand >= 55) {
        Xdif = Player.x + transform.position.x;
        Ydif = Player.y + transform.position.y;
        enemyRun.Update();
        Debug.Log("убегают");       
    }

}

}
```

Подскажите получится ли из этого сделать что-то дельное? На данный момент не работает. Т.е. сейчас враг всегда нападает. При нажатии кнопки лог идет разный(нападают/убегают), но движение враг не меняет.

Comment: игра 2d или 3d? Можно было бы сделать вообще вот так: у объекта со скриптом №1 повесить триггер... ширину/диаметр (в зависимости от типа коллайдера) сделать равной тому значению, которое указано в этом скрипте.... в данном случае  55..всё..у объектов `enemy` по сути всегда будет включен скрипт №3 .... а реакция будет происходить в `OnTriggerEnter` и `OnTriggerExit` чувака со скриптом №1.в `OnTriggerEnter` если `if (collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))` - включить второй скрипт, выключить третий....в `OnTriggerExit` наоборот  `if (collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))` выключить второй включить третий

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский вообще это умение у игрока и оно висит на кнопке. По сути враги всегда нападают, если подойти на определенное расстояние, т.е. работает всегда 2 скрипт. А если нажали кнопку "напугать" то с какой-то вероятностью враг напугается и убежит т.е. сработает скрипт 3. Видимо это не совсем  то, что нужно.

Comment: А, ну если там что-то по кнопке - то да. Просто думал может это самое `fear()` где-то в `Update()` занесено.....можете посмотреть тогда в ответ, который дан ниже

Answer (score 1):

Я  бы сделал еще один скрипт `EnemyController`, в котором храним ссылки на оба скрипта 2 и 3. Создаем метод

```
public void FearActivate(bool active)
{
     enemy.enabled = !active;
     enemyRun.enabled = active;
}
```

Добавьте в скрипт 1 статическую переменную со списком врагов 
`public static List<EnemyController> enemies`. 
Теперь при создании врага(ну или по мере необходимости) через `EnemyController` добавляемся/удаляемся в скрипте 1 в список enemies. Остается в скрипте 1 в `fear` сделать обход по всему циклу зарегестрированных врагов и вызвать метод `FearActivate(rand>=55)`

Comment: А если врагов 1.000? 10.000? 100.000? Думаете целесообразно будет циклом проходить всех врагов?

Comment: Пока не особо ясно что вы точно хотите: Запуск скрипта из другого класса сделал ссылку и вызвал метод.. Вы же сами написали: `Применяться это должно ко всем объектам с тегом "enemy".` Обход списка в любом случае будет дешевле чем поиск всех объектов по тегам на сцене. Если вам нужно чтобы враги по какому то признаку группировались (расстояние до цели, тип врагов, и т.п.) то нужно конечно реализовывать другие варианты. Возможно стоит тогда ориентироваться на использование событий. Пример вошли в радиус действия башни и подписались на событие волна страха от этой башни и т.д.

Comment: Лично МНЕ вообще на всё это плевать, т.к. мне это ничего не нужно

Comment: @KingPeas есть умение "напугать врага", умение вызывается кнопкой. Враги(enemy) если к ним подойти на определенное расстояние нападают на игрока, но при применении этого умения срабатывает вероятность того что враг может напугаться и убежать

Comment: Ну тогда на игроке делаем коллайдер-триггер и при входе в зону игрока контроллер будет запускать одно из поведений. Тогда конечно список не нужен, раз у каждого врага свое поведение.

Comment: @KingPeas у всех врагов одинаковое поведение - нападать и только если применить умение "испуг" то возможно, как выпадет, враг будет убегать пока действует умение.

Comment: Ну тогда @МихаилЧ вам идеально подходит вариант со списком врагов. Если вы хотите чтобы на вашем объекте исполнялся update на каждом кадре нужного скрипта, так этот скрипт надо просто активировать через enabled, а чтобы отключить работу update в другом скрипте на каждом кадре поставьте ему `enemyscript.enabled = false;`